# Puppet doesn't install NPM package or throw errors on package ensure

Tags: npm, puppet

[I'm attempting to write a puppet script that does a jupyterhub server deployment.](https://github.com/jupyter/jupyterhub) I seem to have run into a problem pretty early in the set up steps.

I have

```
class jupyterhub {

    # Used by JupyterHub as a web proxy to notebooks.
    class { 'nodejs':
        manage_package_repo       => false,
        nodejs_dev_package_ensure => 'present',
        npm_package_ensure        => 'latest',
    }

    # Proxy to be used
    package { 'configurable-http-proxy':
        ensure   => present,
        provider => 'npm',
        require  => Class['nodejs'],
    }
```

And on our test server I've run

```
puppet module install puppet-nodejs
```

to have the `nodejs` and `npm` modules

The box I'm running this on is a Debian stable box

```
Debian 3.16.7-ckt11-1+deb8u6 (2015-11-09) x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

When I actually go to run things on the server, however, I find that NPM has been installed but the package wasn't installed.

```
puppet agent --test
Info: Retrieving pluginfacts
Info: Retrieving plugin
Info: Loading facts
Info: Caching catalog for jupyterhub.internal.com
Info: Applying configuration version '1461274246'
Notice: Finished catalog run in 1.68 seconds
$ npm
npm@1.4.21 /usr/share/npm
```

All good so far but when I run

```
npm list
/root
└── (empty)
```

Nothing was installed and I see no errors. I'm deeply confused why this is happening.

Comment: How are you classifying your node with jupyterhub?

Comment: That puppet agent output shows no changes, so it is not the relevant execution for debugging purposes. That being said, try changing that `npm list` to `npm -g list` and see what happens.

Comment: @bigtony I just used a hostname regex to define the time in the root manifest.

Comment: @MattSchuchard I'll have to go look at this later today.